# display lookup multivalue in quickpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, quick-parts

I have a lookup field with multi value.
I'd like using quick part in my template (i know how to use quick part) But i need displaying multiple value (lookup multisel) in a dynamic table.

How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve this at all ? There is a similar question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158249/using-multivalue-dropdown-as-a-quickpart-in-word-document which is not answered either.